# How can i refresh all the page without one component using timer of zk

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk

I'm using timer to refresh all my page `zul`. Is it possible to refresh all the page without one component `("progressmeter")`?

```
<progressmeter style="span.z-progressmeter-image" 
               value="@load(item.progres)" width="110px" height="16px">
</progressmeter>
```

Comment: WITHOUT or WITH one component?

Comment: i mean that i'm using listbox inside this i have many label and one progressmeter of ZK, and when i use timer for 3 second for example i see progress repeat in zero and continue every 3 second , i hope that you understand what i mean?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Assuming that you want to refresh the whole page(Desktop).*

You can refresh the whole page without loosing the state of the `<progressmeter>`, just maintain the Item var on your session and every time the page is reloaded you can recover the last state in the ModelView class, for example:

```
public class MyVm{
....
    private Item item;

@Init
public void initMyVM(){
    Item item = Sessions.getCurrent().getAttribute("myItem");
    if(item == null)
        //do normal intialization
}
public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(Item item) { // or wherever it changes
    this.item = item;
    Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();
    session.setAttribute("myItem", item); // or wherever it changes
}
@Command("onTimer")
pulic void comandRefresh(){
    Executions.sendRedirect("");
}

....

}
```

Now you can refresh your page with  `Executions.sendRedirect("");` any time you want, you will not lost the state of your `<progressmeter/>`. The whole refresh must consider the initialization of your vars on `@Init`.

The other way is to notify changes to all the other vars associated with your View Contenten using  `@NotifyChange`

```
@Command("onTimer")
@NotifyChange({"redrawValue1","RedrawValue2","others"....})
pulic void comandRefresh(){
    Executions.sendRedirect("");
}
```

That means that all your content related with the values of "redrawValue1","RedrawValue2","others"  will be updated on the view. If you need to force a redraw of some areas you can use templates [Template](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVC/View/Template) and associated with fields in your VM in order to use `@NotifyChange` in the same manner.